# Unable to perform this function "php artisan migrate"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laragon

I am unable to launch the homestead in the database of Laragon. It gives me the following error.

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@localhost'

Also, can anyone explain to me how to connect the MySQL server to Laravel from laragon terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your db credentials in .env seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

**You can set Database connectivity in .env file in laravel**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root // username 
DB_PASSWORD="" // password
```

*Or you can set it from path :-* `/app/config/database.php`

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Go To Your Root `you-project-name/` folder you will find .env file there edit your Db credentials in that file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=YOU-DB-NAME
DB_USERNAME=USER-NAME
DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

and then try again this command

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=root
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
                                                                                                                
But I am getting the same error

Comment: your database name is "root" (DB_DATABASE=root)?